# Accessing nested functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code:

```
function getRetailerName(retailerID) {
    var retailerName;
    db.transaction(function retName(qry) {
        qry.executeSql("SELECT retailerName FROM retailers WHERE token = '" + retailerID + "' ", [], function (tx, results1) {
            var len1 = results1.rows.length;
            var retailerName;
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 < len1; i1++) {
                retailerName = results1.rows.item(i1).retailerName;
                //alert(results1.rows.item(i1).retailerName);
            }
        });
        return retailerName;
    });
    alert(retName());
}
```

I am trying to get the value from the inner function `retName()` and ultimately call `getRetailerName()` to get the value from the database, however it keeps giving me an error that `retName` is not defined?

I have tried a lot here,

Comment: where did you define `retName()`?

Comment: SQL INJECTION ALARM! Don't run this code on a real database.

Comment: Use a function with for example this name: `getRetailerNameByToken(token)` and put the sql at the server. This prevent you from SQL INJECTION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like that because it's asynchronous. By the time you return from the function the query hasn't completed. Instead, pass a callback to be executed:

```
function getRetailerName(retailerID, callback) {
    var retailerName;
    db.transaction(function retName(qry) {
        qry.executeSql("SELECT retailerName FROM retailers WHERE token = '" + retailerID + "' ", [], function (tx, results1) {
            var len1 = results1.rows.length;
            var retailerName;
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 < len1; i1++) {
                retailerName = results1.rows.item(i1).retailerName;
                callback(retailerName);
            }
        });
    });
}

getRetailerName(1, function(name) {
    alert(name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (since the `retName` named function expression is only available inside it) and You should not try to do this (since the functions are asynchronous and it wouldn't work). Instead, use callbacks:

```
function getRetailerName(retailerID, callback) {
    var retailerName;
    db.transaction(function retName(qry) {
        qry.executeSql("SELECT retailerName FROM retailers WHERE token = '" + retailerID + "' ", [], function (tx, results1) {
            var len1 = results1.rows.length;
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 < len1; i1++) {;
                callback(results1.rows.item(i1).retailerName);
            }
        });
    });
}

getRetailerName(1, alert.bind(window));
```